# Does an ipv6 anycast address generated

Tags: ipv6, mac-address, dhcp, nic

I read from the rfc that anycast addresses are derived from unicast addresses, but unicast addresses' interface identifiers(IID) is of EUI-64 format, which is generated by link layer address, so we can indicate a link layer address from a unicast address.

So, how are anycast addresses' IIDs generated. It doesn't comply to the EUI-64 format any more, any one can answer my question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can select any address within the subnet as an anycast address, except for the reserved addresses in [RFC 2526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2526).